# Editbox portion of ComboBox gets selected automatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a small problem that has been annoying me for some hours.

In my WinForms (.NET 3.5) application I create some ComboBoxes (DropDownStyle = DropDown) in a TableLayoutPanel at runtime and fill it with strings. The ComboBoxes are configured to resize automatically (Anchor = Left | Right).

The problem is that whenever the ComboBoxes are resized (i.e. the dialog is resized), the editbox portion of the ComboBox gets selected/highlighted entirely. In my opinion this creates a very confusing effect for the customer which I want to avoid.

The problem doesn't appear if the ComboBox has a fixed size.

Also note that changing the DropDownStyle is not an option - I need the possibility to enter text manually.

I already tried messing around with overriding the OnPaint method, which didn't quite work.
I also tried clearing the selection in the ComboBox.Resize event, which worked in a way, but seemed like a very ugly solution - there was a lot of flicker, intentionally selected text became deselected and I would have to add the event handler to each and every ComboBox on my dialog.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Andy

Comment: The text portion isn't editable when you use DropDownList. Did you mean DropDown?

Answer (score 17):

This is an old question, but I found it searching for an answer and ended up implementing my own solution. Might as well post it here, right?

```
    foreach (var cb in Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
    {
        cb.Resize += (sender, e) => {
            if (!cb.Focused)
                cb.SelectionLength = 0;
        };
    }
```

> intentionally selected text became deselected

This WinForms bug doesn't affect selected ComboBoxes, so by ignoring the ones with Focus, we take care of the problem of losing current selections.

> I would have to add the event handler
>   to each and every ComboBox on my
>   dialog.

Taken care of by the foreach loop. Put it in InitializeComponent() or your .ctor if you don't want to break the designer, or have the designer break this.

> there was a lot of flicker

I'm only seeing flicker if I resize very fast, but I'm on Win7 so it might be different on XP.

Comment: I wanted to suggest to do a this.SelectNextControl  or a combobox.SelectNextControl

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's been bugging me for awhile and only just now got 'round to fixing it.  Every combo-box type control in my app inherits from a base object (so I can have a label, common methods, etc).  Putting in an OnResize event handler for the combo box has addressed my issue, rather than having to iterate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers so far worked for me. The only reliable method I have found was to post a message asynchronously via `BeginInvoke` that sets `SelectionLength` back to zero after all other activity on the control has completed. The amount of flicker is very annoying and unprofessional, but it is the best I could come up with...so far.

```
internal class FixedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsHandleCreated && !Focused)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    SelectionLength = 0;
                }));
        }
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the other answers here didn't work for you because your `ComboBox` was in a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: @JeffRoe: I don't remember the details. It was too long ago, but yes, that is very possible.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in the native Windows implementation of `ComboBox` with `DropDownStyle` of `DropDown`.

The fix detailed in the other answers here (setting the `SelectionLength` property to 0 (zero) in the `ComboBox`'s `Resize` event) works well most of the time.

However, I found that even that fix to work around this bug does not always work.  If the `ComboBox` is in a `TableLayoutPanel`, and if that `TableLayoutPanel` has more than one column with a `Percent` Size Type, then that fix often does not work.

A picture is worth a thousand words.  See the following screen shot of a form I made to demonstrate the problem.

[image]

Comment: I was able to solve this by using the TableLayoutPanel Resize event.  `foreach (ComboBox cbo in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) tableLayoutPanel1.Resize += (s, e) => { if (!cbo.Focused) cbo.SelectionLength = 0; };`

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me to change the selectionLength to 0 when the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` gets called.
Works even with the tableLayoutPanel set to %.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if(m.Msg == 0x0047) {   // WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047 
        if (SelectionLength != 0) {
            SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow. Thank you guys!

Apparently this bug has persisted many years.
I'm building a UserControl with .Net 4 (Visual Studio 2010).
Here's is my slightlty modified version of bsneeze's code.

Cheers

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

public MyUserControlCtor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach( Control ctrl in Controls)
    {
        ComboBox cb = ctrl as ComboBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            cb.Resize += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!cb.Focused)
                    this.FCHZ_ComboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            };
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I like this notation much better 
foreach (var cb in Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())

Answer (score 1):

Handle the Resize event for the ComboBox's parent container.  Put this line in there:

MyComboBox.SelectionLength = 0

An Example (VB, obviously):

```
Private Sub MyControl_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize

    MyComboBox.SelectionLength = 0

End Sub
```

Good Luck to you!

--BP

Answer (score 0):

I found setting the selection length to 0 for the combo-box on the resize event of whatever control the combo-box is on causes a **lot** less flickering instead of doing it on the resize of the combo itself.

I actually achieved this in VB.Net but it should apply the same to C#.

Answer (score 0):

For a ComboBox inside a TableLayoutPanel setting the .SelectionLength = 0 on the ComboBox.Resize event does not work, but doing this on the TableLayoutPanel.Resize event does:

```vb
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim curr_panel = TryCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel)
    For Each curr_combo As ComboBox In curr_panel.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
        If ((Not curr_combo.Focused) And curr_combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown) Then
                curr_combo.SelectionLength = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub


dim panel as new TableLayoutPanel with {
    ...
}
AddHandler panel.Resize, AddressOf TableLayoutPanel_Resize
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep this one is still around, and it's not specific to being on a TableLayoutPanel. ComboBox just does this.

Regardless what point in the stack you insert a correction to this undesired behavior, I see that the generally suggested correction is to let it go ahead and Select All, and then quickly set SelectionLength = 0 afterward.

That's still a pretty visible flash it makes, highlighting all text and then unhighlighting it. Can I suggest a flash so mild you may not even see it? **Remove the text, let ComboBox do its thing with nothing to select, then put the text back.** It would go something like this...

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_COMMAND)
    {
        if (m.WParam.ToInt32() >> 16 == EN_SETFOCUS)
        {
            // Unnecessary Select All #1: it wants to select all whenever you click on it.
            // Solution: Remove all text. Checkmate.
            _resizing = true;
            string temp = Text;
            Text = "";
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            Text = temp;
            _resizing = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (m.Msg == WM_SIZE)
    {
        // Unnecessary Select All #2: it wants to select all whenever you resize.
        // Solution: Remove all text again.
        _resizing = true;
        string temp = Text;
        Text = "";
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        Text = temp;
        _resizing = false;
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}

protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_resizing) base.OnTextChanged(e);
}
```