# Winforms Combobox selects text on Forms fontchange

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have never noted strange behaviour on Comboboxes until now. For see what is happening you may create a minimal example. Open a new project, put textbox, two comboboxes with `DropDownStyle=DropDown` (what is initial) and button on it and paste following code to Form.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    TextBox1.Text = "Mess"
    Button1.Text = "Increase Font"
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"One", "Two", "Three"})
    ComboBox1.Text = "Two"
    ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({"Left", "Right", "Up", "Down"})
    ComboBox2.Text = "Up"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.Name, Me.Font.Size + 1)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
End Class
```

What is happenning is that in case of pressing a Button1 Form's fontsize increases and Comboboxes selects his text! That way my GUI becames messed.

Did anybody know how to get rid of that and get Comboboxes with expected functionality?

Comment: Amazing! People already had this issue [C# Highlighted text in WinForms combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062408/c-sharp-highlighted-text-in-winforms-combo-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem to be some problem in framework. Consider it "funny behavior". But you can do this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.Name, Me.Font.Size + 1)
    TextBox1.Focus()
    ComboBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    ComboBox2.SelectionLength = 0

End Sub
```

If your cbo is sub-classed as you pointed in the comment than in your super class add

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Layout(sender As Object, e As LayoutEventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.Layout
    DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).SelectionLength = 0
End Sub
```

this works for all cbo's on the form

```
Private Sub Form1_Layout(sender As Object, e As LayoutEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Layout
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        Dim combo As ComboBox = TryCast(c, ComboBox)
        If combo IsNot Nothing AndAlso combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown Then
            combo.SelectionLength = 0
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, if you have 10 or more blue comboboxes on form then form look's "really funny". I try your solution before. It is not good enough since I would like some systematic fix for that because all my comboboxes are subcalssed and I can apply possible fix centralized. However font change is on other place, on subclassed form :) This is just minimal example which I take out to prove a problem for myself and for others.

Comment: Interesting:     Protected Overrides Sub OnLayout(levent As LayoutEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLayout(levent)
        Me.SelectionLength = 0
    End Sub
This works partially. On some font sizes text is still selected. Problem must lay somewhere deeper. My comboboxes are not selected when they was set like in those second topic. But when it is resized. This is the difference.

Comment: After all I see that this is generic problem, as usual with MS "more bug than a feature" and solution should be searched in owner drawed Comboboxes.

Comment: @WineToo So, when I said, *"It seem to be some problem in framework"*, you didn't believe just to declare *"After all I see that this is generic problem"*. I thought, my answer was exactly that. Don't you think that these 2 statements saying same thing?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I accept your answer no matter what we havent find some better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @WineToo Ok. Thanks. I don't think anyone solved it "the right way"