# Prevent resize from selecting all text in focused ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox with DropDownStyle of DropDown that is resized whenever the window is resized. If there is at least one Item in the ComboBox and it is chosen, resizing the ComboBox selects all the text, blowing away the user's previous text selection. This also occurs when the window loses focus and then regains it. Has anyone figured out a way to prevent this from happening, or of restoring the text selection after this occurs?

[image: The user selects some text...] [image: ...and it is blown away when the ComboBox is resized.]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/786119/237285) describes a related problem for unfocused ComboBoxes and contains a solution that resets SelectionLength to 0 after the Resize event. This event would be a good candidate place for restoring the text selection, but I'm not sure how to get the text selection *before* it was blown away by the resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I'm not sure how to get the text selection before it was blown away by the resize

You can gather this in the form `ResizeBegin` event.

```
private int _start;   
private int _length;

private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _start = comboBox1.SelectionStart;
    _length = comboBox1.SelectionLength;
}

private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectionStart = _start;
    comboBox1.SelectionLength = _length;
}
```

*Or continually set it back when the combobox resizes (can also being done in the form resize event itself to of coarse, depends how you like it)*. With this option the user will not see any change. In the above example the whole text will be selected while the form is resizing. In the below one it will not.

```
private int _start;   
private int _length;

private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _start = comboBox1.SelectionStart;
    _length = comboBox1.SelectionLength;
}

private void comboBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectionStart = _start;
    comboBox1.SelectionLength = _length;
}
```

Alternatively you can do this for different events, such as when the form loses focus etc.

```
private int _start;    
private int _length;

private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveComboBoxSelectionState(comboBox1);
}

private void comboBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetComboBoxSelection(comboBox1, _start, _length);
}

private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    SaveComboBoxSelectionState(comboBox1);
}

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetComboBoxSelection(comboBox1, _start, _length);
}

private void SaveComboBoxSelectionState(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    _start = comboBox.SelectionStart;
    _length = comboBox.SelectionLength;
}

private void SetComboBoxSelection(ComboBox comboBox, int start, int length)
{
    comboBox.SelectionStart = start;
    comboBox.SelectionLength = length;
}
```